# How can i get the values of from and two from the character

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I am having some issue in the progress bar so always `0km` is added to the result value.

If i select 18 - 48 it is displaying like

`18 - 480km`

How can i get the `18` and `48` from the result.

I tried to

`var ageSearch = ageSearchval.slice(0,-1);`

but it is outputing like `18 - 420k`

So, How can i get those values in two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should slice with `-3` characters and then split with `-`

So, Your code should look like

`var ageSearch = ageSearchval.slice(0,-3);`

and then

```
var ageSearcharr = ageSearch.split(' - ');
var From = ageSearcharr[0];
var To = ageSearcharr[1];
```

Now, You will have 18 in the `From` and 48 in the `To`

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allaudeen/3kgLdnmc/)

```js
var ageSearchval = `18 - 480km`;
var ageSearch = ageSearchval.slice(0,-3);
var ageSearcharr = ageSearch.split(' - ');
var From = ageSearcharr[0];
var To = ageSearcharr[1]; 
alert(From);
alert(To);
```